# Error when removing directory from hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I try to remove directory from hdfs , then following message shows

```
vmm1@ubuntu1:~$ hadoop fs -rm -r /user/vmm1/stlist
```

> rm: Failed to get server trash configuration: null. Consider using
>   -skipTrash option

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...
Add this property to hdfs-site.xml file

```
<property>
<name>fs.trash.interval</name>
<value>5</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe just use -skipTrash option to pass the null config.
eg. hadoop fs -rm -R -skipTrash /user/test

this worked for me, hope this can help you.